# Background: url() using .attrs() function

Tags: styled-components

I'm trying to display a different background depending on props with .attrs();

I have the following;

```
const Heart = styled.div.attrs(props => ({
    background: `url(${props => props.filled ? "./media/heart-filled.png" : "./media/heart-empty.png"})`
}))`
//rest of styles here.
`;
```

However, it doesn't display anything. How exactly does this function work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you're trying to use `.attrs` here, but it's used to attache some props to a styled component.

https://styled-components.com/docs/api#attrs

To make your code work, you could try:

```
const Heart = styled.div.attrs(props => ({/* Some aditional props here ! */}))`
   background: url(${props => (props.filled ? "./media/heart-filled.png" : "./media/heart-empty.png")}); /* props that you pass into your component can be used here */
   /* rest of styles here. */
`;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-brown-lx0lf?file=/src/App.js